# How to simulate/trigger keydown of tab in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, automation, dom-events

I'm trying to trigger a keydown of the <kbd>tab</kbd> key in JavaScript.

**Scenario:** 2 HTML input elements. Initially focus is on the 1st input, then wait 3 seconds, then simulate pressing of the tab key, which should set focus to the 2nd input.

**Issue:** Dispatching a <kbd>tab</kbd> `keydown` event does nothing.

**Fiddles:**

- Using KeyboardEvent & dispatchEvent - http://jsfiddle.net/dH9ZE/
- Using simulant.js - http://jsfiddle.net/3E5dB/

I am after a JavaScript solution. No jQuery thanks.

**Fiddle example using simulant.js below:**

HTML:

```
<input id="first">
<input id="second">
<p>Dispatching Tab keydown event in 3 seconds... <span id="done" style="color:red"></span></p>
```

JavaScript:

```
//simulates keydown of the tab key
function simulateTab() {
    var TAB_KEY = 9;    
    simulant.fire(document, 'keydown', { keyCode: TAB_KEY });
}

//focus 'first' input
document.getElementById('first').focus();

//focus 'second' input after 3 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    simulateTab();
    document.getElementById('done').innerHTML = 'Done!';
}, 3000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate keypress without jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323279/simulate-keypress-without-jquery)

Comment: The apparent 'duplicate' solution did not work.

Comment: I have looked through all answers with both duplicate questions, none of them work. No wonder none of the answers have been marked as accepted!