# Fire keyboard event in Javascript without deprecated functions or libraries

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, keyboard-events

I was trying to find a cross browser solution using Javascript that would allow me to send a keypress or keydown event to an input or textarea without using jQuery.

My research shows that [KeyboardEvent.initKeyEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent), [KeyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent) are all deprecated which means that [Firing a keyboard event in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/961532/firing-a-keyboard-event-in-javascript), [Simulate keypress without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323279/simulate-keypress-without-jquery), and [simulate javascript key events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events) are questions with obsolete answers.

Is there a cross browser way that isn't deprecated to send an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key event to a DOM element?