# Simulating keyboard press in a way that isn't deprecated?

Tags: javascript, deprecated

I am looking for a way to simulate a keyboard press (like the titled suggests).  I have looked around and I have found mainly these 2 SO questions:

- [Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/simulate-javascript-key-events)
- [Simulate keypress without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323279/simulate-keypress-without-jquery)

The issue with those are that they both use the `KeyboardEvent.initKeyboardEvent()` event which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent) it is deprecated.  Is there a different way of accomplishing the same thing without that deprecated function?

I would like to know this because I am creating a script for YouTube using Chrome's TamperMonkey extension.  This script will, when <kbd>[space]</kbd> is pressed, trigger <kbd>K</kbd>.  <kbd>K</kbd> is YouTube's toggle play/pause button.  I have the <kbd>[space]</kbd> listener working perfectly with the code below:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode==32) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Also I am really looking for a pure JavaScript approach.

Comment: Possibly useful. From MDN: "Web applications should use constructor instead of this if it's available." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent

Comment: Can you explain WHAT you are attempting? That will result in better answers

Comment: @mplungjan I am attempting to, when a user does a specific action (click a button or similar), this function will be triggered to make the page believe a specific key on the keyboard has been pressed.

Comment: what is stopping you from executing the same callback on both types of events - user pressing a key or clicking on a button?

Comment: @Aprillion I made the question much more general.  I am creating a script in a chrome extension that does not have direct access to the web page's code.  I am making the script for YouTube to, when `[space]` is pressed, it will trigger `K`.  `K` is YouTube's toggle play/pause button.  I have the `[space]` listener working, but I cant seem to  trigger `K`.  I will edit my question to be a little more specific.

Comment: Can you access youtube's API from your extension? (i.e. do you have access to `window.YT`?)  If so, using that API directly would be a lot simpler than the roundabout approach of simulating keyboard events.

Comment: @CollinD I have just finished reading through that MDN page, and, unless I am mistaken, that function seems to only listen for the event, as the functions (different gecko and webkit) that initiate the event are both deprecated.

Comment: @Jaketr00 Maybe I misunderstood, but it looks like you can use the optional second parameter to initialize an event. The docs aren't very clear on that though I agree. Maybe worth some testing.

Comment: @DanielBeck It seems I do have access to that, what would be the correct way to toggle playback with that function?

Comment: Get the individual player instance from `window.YT`, then call `.playVideo()` or `.pauseVideo()` on it.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Comment: @DanielBeck I am not using an iframe, I am on the YouTube site.  I have been trying to run `YT.Player.playVideo()`, but I get `YT is not defined`, then `yt.playVideo() is not a function`, and I have tried a bunch of variences like `yt.player.playVideo()` and `window.yt.player.playVide()` but nothing is working.  But thanks for the article.

Comment: I see, I assumed you were working with embeds, sorry.  On the youtube site itself, `window.yt.player` exists (note lowercase), and has a `getPlayerByElement()` function; you may be able to use that to find the correct player object, though off the top of my head I'm not sure if the API will be usable there.

Comment: @DanielBeck I would like to add, I found this github project https://gist.github.com/VioletRed/d3678cdc700cd4d62fec and I read through it and found out that on the YT website you can use `window.document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].pause()` and `window.document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play()` for HTML5 video.  There is also a Flash fallback in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this with jQuery you build your event.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368599/3257830

If you want to create an event, you initialize the object then dispatch the event.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
  alert(e.which);
});
var e = new Event("keypress");
e.which = 65;
e.keyCode = 65;
document.dispatchEvent(e);
```

```html
<p id="r">Alerts on event</p>
```

Comment: Could someone explain why this was down-voted? I'm not defending the answer, just trying to learn.

Comment: See the edit history.  Downvotes are likely from when the answer was completely irrelevant to the question

Comment: This works great, except when I add `if (e.keyCode==65)` inside the keypress listener, this seems to not be triggered.  I will test this in my script and see if it still works.  EDIT: It does not seem to work, it just silently fails, and `event.preventDefault()` is supposed to stop the page from scrolling when `[space]` is pressed, but with the above script it does not prevent that anymore

Comment: @Jaketr00 keyCode and which are 2 separate properties. If you want keyCode then add keyCode in your initialization as well. I edited my above answer to allow for keyCode to be checked as well.

Comment: Oh ok, that helps with my if statement.