# How to mimic $jQuery.trigger exactly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, input, google-chrome-extension

I have a website that won't accept values inserted into `INPUT` element's `value` directly via JS. The only way it works if I try to imitate sending `space` key via jQuery (which is bundled with web-site) after changing the value itself:

```
elem.value = 'Im so tried of meme frameworks';
elem.focus();
press = jQuery.Event("keypress");
press.which = 32;
$(elem).trigger(press);
```

While this works, I want to avoid **injecting** code to use on-site jQuery or bundle jQuery with extension (it is 20-30 times larger than whole extension). I sought alternatives, but to my surprise NONE of them work -- or rather produce the same result as jQuery's one -- in in Chrome 114 in 2023:

Old `KeyboardEvent Dispatch`:
[Keydown Simulation in Chrome fires normally but not the correct key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455626/keydown-simulation-in-chrome-fires-normally-but-not-the-correct-key)

[Simulating keyboard press in a way that isn't deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35227608/simulating-keyboard-press-in-a-way-that-isnt-deprecated)

[Is it possible to simulate key press events programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically)

Just `Event`:
[Trigger a keypress/keydown/keyup event in JS/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368578/trigger-a-keypress-keydown-keyup-event-in-js-jquery/3368599#3368599)

And so on. Even seems to be firing but `space` "press" never ever registered or felt by input field in any way.

What magic does jQuery pull off that we can't do?

Comment: Have you tried `elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('change', { bubbles: true }));` after changing the input's value?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Comment: @IvánNokonoko tried pretty much everything

Comment: Try the deprecated document.execCommand, [example](/a/57900849).

Comment: @wOxxOm Nice, this works!