# Simulate keypress into <input> WITHOUT jQuery

Tags: javascript, html

How do I simulate a keypress into a input tag without jQuery? I looked at [Simulate keypress without jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323279/simulate-keypress-without-jquery)
but it didn't seem to help. Example of what I'm trying to do:

```js
<inputobject>.simulatekeypress('a');
```

Please do **not** submit any jquery answers.

Comment: Do you want to programmatically stuff a character into a `<input>` box? What happens to the existing value in the input box, do you overwrite it?

Comment: > Do you want to programmatically stuff a character into a <input> box?
yes

Comment: Why not just set the value?

Answer (score -1):

```js
function simulatekeypress(char) { 
  document.getElementById("input").value += char;
}

// simulatekeypress("a");
```

```html
Input: <input id="input" value="123" />
<p>
  <button onclick="simulatekeypress('a');">
    Simulate key press
  </button>
</p>
```